# PHPExcel Dynamic column range is not working

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

I'm a novice to PHP. Here, I am getting an empty table while applying the below code for setting the columns name dynamic.

Here, `$highestColumm` ideally it should be int value of number of columns.

```
<table>
   <?php  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName('Excel Sheet'); 

         $highestColumm = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();  
         $highestRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();  

         $highestColumm++;
         for ($row = 1; $row < $highestRow + 1; $row++) {     
             $dataset = array();     
             for ($column = 'A'; $column != $highestColumm; $column++) {
                 $dataset[] = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getCell($column . $row)->getValue();
             }
             $datasets[] = $dataset;
          }
    ?>                                     
        <tbody>
                @for($i=1;$i<=$highestColumm;$i++)
                   @php 
                      @$dataC = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getCell('A'.@$i)->getCalculatedValue(); 
                   @endphp
                                          
                <tr>
                     <td @php @$name = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getCell('A'.@$i)->getCalculatedValue(); @endphp {{@$name}} </td>
                     <td @if(@$i==1) @endif>@php @$name = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getCell('B'.@$i)->getCalculatedValue(); @endphp {{@$name}} </td>
                     <td @if(@$i==1) @endif>@php @$name = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getCell('C'.@$i)->getCalculatedValue(); @endphp {{@$name}} </td>                   
                </tr>

                @endfor
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Can i use HTML inside PHP will that in this case?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the value of `$highestColumm` when you first define it?

Comment: @BadHorsie Here I'm trying to keep the value of variable `$highestColumm` as number of columns.

Comment: Yes but you need to debug your code to find which part is not working. If you put `var_dump($highestColumn);` after you first try to set the value, what is its value?

Comment: @BadHorsie, I have multiple columns in this case for every sheet. And I want to keep the variable $highestColumm as a number of columns for each sheet for each table which I will be creating in HTML.

Comment: @This code is return in HTML file will this `var_dump()` will work?

Comment: I'm just helping you to debug your code. This will not fix it. The idea is to find where your problem is. You need to know what the value of `$highestColumn` is at the start, to see if there is a problem with it. Perhaps it's not getting the value correctly from the spreadsheet, which prevents your table from showing anything.